# Определение количества элементов в массиве

Tags: c++

Сейчас я определяю количество элементов в статическом массиве с помощью следующего выражения:

```
sizeof(Array)/sizeof(Array[0])
```

Я слышал, что существует стандартный макрос для этого действия, скажите как он называется или, может быть, существует более простой способ?

Comment: Под массивом видимо подразумевается сишный "статический" массив, т.е. с постоянной длиной? Поскольку для динамических массивов данный способ не подойдет.

Comment: Да, именно статический. Исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 13):

```
template<typename T, size_t n>
inline size_t arraySize(const T (&arr)[n])
{
    return n;
}
```

По сравнению с упомянутым макросом минусов, я лично, не вижу. Любой компилятор подобный вызов заоптимизирует просто в константу.

Есть ли какие-то плюсы? Думаю, да. Макросы — это штука такая довольно мутная. С ними очень легко ошибиться (см. комментарии к предыдущему ответу). Один раз определённый макрос будет потом болтаться и там, где его можно не ожидать. Эта же штука ведёт себя как любая другая функция. Её даже IntelliSense видит и автодополняет! :).

Comment: Единственное отличие от макроса в том, что до C++0x эта функция не constexpr, а, значит, неприменима для создания массива того же размера, что и данный (и аналогичных задач).

Comment: данный шаблон не будет работать для строк объявленных в таком виде:
const char* str="str";
А если перегрузить чтобы принимались соответствующие указатели, то будет тоже неверно, поскольку можно будет передавать указатели на объекты для которых вычисление длины станет не корректным. По этому, ставлю минус за ответ.

Лично мое мнение: для таких задач не надо писать ни макросы ни придумывать шаблоны, нужно просто вставлять маленький код уже упомянутый в задаче.

Comment: @IAZ к сожалению, для указанного Вами примера вообще никакой код работать не будет, даже упомянутый в вопросе. Длину такой строки невозможно определить в compile-time — только strlen. Не забывайте, что вопрос был именно про определение длины статических массивов.

Comment: @kirelagin а ведь точно, у меня при проверке совпало с длиной указателя 4 :( минус снимаю

Comment: @IAZ :). У меня тоже при первой проверке совпало с длиной указателя и я серьёзно задумался =).

Answer (score 4):

В MSVC есть отличный макрос: [_countof()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(v=vs.80).aspx). Он как раз и разворачивается в конструкции вида sizeof(Array)/sizeof(Array[0])

Answer (score 2):

Возможно что и существует подобный макрос в какой нибудь библиотеке, но в Стандарте разумеется такого нет. Да и что мешает написать самому макрос раз так нужен!?

PS: для сишных массивов с постоянной длиной более правильного способа не существует.

Comment: Что-то типа  
#define arraySize(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

Comment: Да именно так, только с поправкой #define arraySize(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof((a)[0])) .

Comment: В данный момент такой и использую, интересовал вопрос наличия стандартного.

Comment: @Евген стандартного нет, инфа 100%.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int n=3;
 int v[n];
 cout<<sizeof(v)<<endl;
 cout<<sizeof(v)/sizeof(int);
}
```

Довольно простое решение задачи, не?

Comment: вопрос уже содержит: `sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0])`. Автор спрашивает, есть ли более простой способ или стандартный макрос.