# Массивы и их размер

Tags: c++, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста:

1. Как объявить массив, но без размера?
2. Или как найти размер инициализированного массива?

Пример ко второму вопросу. 
Есть массивы `char arr1[15], arr2[15];` мы их инициализируем так `arr1 = {sasha}, arr2 = {sashavorobey}`. И нужно сравнить равны ли по размеру инициализированные элементы массива.

Постарался, как можно более информативно задать вопрос. Ибо только начинаю изучать самостоятельно и не всегда нахожу ответ сам.

Comment: [Опереление количества элементов массива](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2332/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5). Массив без размера (а не размерности) же объявить не удастся (размер его может быть автоматически вычислен из списка инициализации при определении массива, но не иначе, т.е. например `int a[] = {1, 2, 3}`), т.к. под массив память выделяется на стеке, а не в куче.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive объявление массива без размера: `extern int a[];`

Comment: @alexolut А когда присвоишь такому массиву 3 значения, то у него тогда появиться размер? 
И он при вызове `sizeof()`, вернется 3?

Comment: @alexolut Я хотел с акцентировать на этом внимание, но уже появились ответы к этому моменту и я забил (стоило бы указать на определение массива и расписать подробности).

Comment: @Vorobey.A Приведенный пример с `extern int a[];` это лишь объявление некой переменной `a`, которая является массивом какого-то размера, который где-то в этом приложении определен (а вот там, где он определен размер заведомо известен), т.е. он обязан быть определен где-нибудь в другом места данного приложения, т.к. иначе выскочит ошибка линковки.

Comment: @Vorobey.A объявление - это не определение. `extern int a[];` говорит о том, что массив определен (выделена память под него) где-то в другом месте. Если это определение находится в другой единице трансляции, или хотя бы где-то ниже места попытки вызова `sizeof`, то эта попытка вообще приведет к ошибке компиляции.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так как Вы указали тег C++, то логичнее использовать не сишные массивы, а контейнеры из стандартной библиотеки C++. Например, **[std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/)** или **[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)**. Объявляются они, как с размером, так и без размера. Также имеют метод **size()**, возвращающий их размер. Доступ к элементам осуществляется по индексу **[ ]**. Как вариант, для работы с символами можно использовать ***std::string***, к которому тоже это все относится.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

    int main ()
    {
      std::vector<char> arr1={'s','h','a','s','h','a','1'};
      std::cout << "size of arr1: " << arr1.size() << std::endl;
      std::string arr2="shasha2";
      std::cout << "size of arr2: " << arr2.size() << std::endl;
      std::array<char,6> arr3{'s','h','a'};
      std::cout << "size of arr3: " << arr3.size() << std::endl;

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: нет такого понятия в C++ как STL.

Comment: @ixSci Ну конечно же нет такого **[понятия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)**. *Просто "большинство людей ее так называют"*. Так уж повелось.

Comment: То что большинство называет вещи **неправильно**, не повод это повторять. Создаётся впечатление, что есть C++, а есть какая-то отдельная STL. Но это неправда, C++ не отделим от своей библиотеки, и чем раньше человек это осознает, тем проще ему будет использовать язык.

Comment: @ixSci Да, возможно. Но чтобы человек начал что-то осознавать - ему это необходимо доносить понятным ему языком. А дальше он сам уже разберется. P.S: по Вашему убедительному настоянию я внес правку в ответ.

Comment: @MaxZS: а ещё, если можно, исправьте «размерность» на «размер».

Answer (score 2):

Массивы имеют ровно такой размер, который вы ему выделили при инициализации:

```
char s[] = "asd";
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
int b[10] = {1, 2, 3};
std::cout << sizeof(s) << std::endl; // выведет 4, учитывается символ '\0' в конце
std::cout << sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) << std::endl; // выведет 3
std::cout << sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]) << std::endl; // выведет 10
```

Массивы без размерности лучше не использовать, они считаются незавершенным типом, их размер узнать невозможно. В моём примере они сразу инициализируются, и им автоматически сопоставляется размер. Этого не произойдёт, если не сделать инициализации при объявлении:

```
int a[];
a = {1, 2, 3};
std::cout << sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) << std::endl; // ошибка компиляции - размер 'а' неизвестен.
```

Так же можно использовать `std::array` - массив фиксированного размера или `std::vector` - массив динамически изменяемого размера

```
std::vector<int> a;
a = {1, 2, 3};
std::cout << a.size() << std::endl; // выведет 3
a.push_back(4);
std::cout << a.size() << std::endl; // выведет 4
```

Для строк можно так же использовать `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

1. Массив без размерности это string попробуй их поюзать 2. там и сравнивать их легко.
   string a = "бла бла";
   strbng s = "блаааа";
   if (a != s)
   {код условия}
   Я бы так сделал....если надо сравнивать набор символов....

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, у которых возникнет такой же вопрос с определением размера заполненного массива, я нашел хороший способ найти его)) Привожу код ниже:

```
char arr1[15];
int k = 0;    

gets_s(arr1); // Пользователь вводит не 15 символов, а допустим 4

for (int i = 0; arr1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        k++;
    }// после цикла в счетчике будет 4 - как раз размер инициализированного массива
```

`\0` считается завершающим символом.

Надеюсь кому-то может помочь)