# С++ получить количество элементов в массиве

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Подскажите, как можно получить кол-во элементов массива? Пробовал

```
sizeof(array) / sizeof(char *)
```

Но результат получался странным: в массиве 1 элемент, а оно выводило "2".
Как можно реализовать на С++?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2332/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5

Comment: Вы бы хоть сказали, что такое `array`...

Comment: array - сам массив.

Comment: @free_ze, пробовал так, не помогает. Массив json, выглядит так:
{"data":[{"id": "123456", "name": "Alex"}, {"id": "123457", "name": "Vasiliy"}]}

Вызвать элементы могу так: array["data"][0]["id"], но получить количество элементов не получается :(

Comment: Значит, это не массив С/С++, а, скорее всего, объект какого-то класса. Если поделить число дней в году на ваш вес, вряд ли мы получим частоту вашего процессора...

Comment: Как именно объявлен `array`? Приведите в вопросе строку, где создаётся эта переменная.

Answer (score 0):

Значит в массиве находиться элемент, чей размер занимает:

```
размер = 2 умножить на размер char*
```

т.е 2 размерам указателя. А размер указателя зависит от разрядности машины на которой компилируете и от разрядности приложения.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

Но вообще нужно проверять есть ли в массиве хоть один элемент
Это массив чего?

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T, int n> // size_t n
int array_size(T (&a)[n]) { return n; }
```