# Как посчитать количество строк в массиве строк (string)?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Мне нужно посчитать сколько строк (элементов) в массиве строк. Может быть есть какая-то функция, определяющая верхний индекс массива? Или что-то подобное?
В counter будет записано количество строк.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    string str[4] = { "привет", "пока", "g", "l" };
    //...
cout << counter << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Взять длину массива?

Comment: @entithat да. P.S.: я дополнил вопрос

Comment: вы же сами задали размер массива 4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4108340/7791165

Comment: @VTT это в тренировочных целях. У меня есть другая программа, в которой массив в зависимости от того, к какому классу он принадлежит имеет разное количество элементов (не динамический массив). Мне нужно определить сколько в нём слов

Comment: Тогда приводите пример *реального* кода.

Comment: @VTT он слишком большой и непонятный. Это ни к чему, т.к. очень долго придется вникать в то, что и как делает программа

Comment: "пример реального кода" не подразумевает вываливание сюда всей вашей программы. Вам следует ознакомиться с [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Определение количества элементов в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2332/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такая стандартная шаблонная функция [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), которая позволяет определить количество элементов в массиве или контейнере.

```
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 3, 1, 4 };
    std::cout << std::size(v) << '\n'; 

    int a[] = { -5, 10, 15 };
    std::cout << std::size(a) << '\n';
}
```

Можно, конечно, написать свою шаблонную функцию, или воспользоваться  решением в стиле C:

```
sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0])
```

Заметим только, что при передаче массива в функцию, принимающую именно массив как таковой, или указатель на массив, т.е. в вашем случае, скажем,

```
void f(string s[]);
void g(string * s);
```

этот фокус не сработает, потому что фактически в функцию будет передан указатель на первый элемент массива.

P.S. К вашему

> массив в зависимости от того, к какому классу он принадлежит имеет разное количество элементов

А вы не хотите использовать `vector` или `array`? Если уж используете `string` - то вряд ли у вас такое жесткое ограничение на массивы. Или, если уж у вас массив является членом класса - то вы, вероятно, обращаетесь к нему через интерфейс класса - ну так добавьте в этот интерфейс функцию-член, возвращающую размер массива.

Comment: Не то чтобы это неправильный ответ, но в примере, который привел ОП, *ничего*  из вышеперечисленного не нужно. А что реально происходит в его программе - это еще большой вопрос.